# Trigger Alertify alert on PHP insert query

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, alertify

I’d like to trigger an [Alertify](https://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) alert by PHP. Right now the alert occurs when the button is clicked, but I want to make the alert appear when a PHP insert query is successful.

My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.run').click(function(event){
            alertify.alert('Housing successfully updated.').show();
        });
    });

</script>

<button class="run">Show alert</button>
```

Comment: What query are you talking about?

Comment: for example i have a php insert query, then after if the query if successfull i want to show the alertify, data successfully added.. like that

Comment: So is it a form submission, ajax call, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//query<br/>
$insert = your query;<br/>
                if($insert){<br/>
                    $_SESSION['modal'] = "success";<br/>
                    header('location: redirect');<br/>
                }else{<br/>
                    $_SESSION['modal'] = "failed";<br/>
                    header('location: redirect');<br/>
                }<br/>

//load the session and show alert <br/>
    if(isset($_SESSION['modal'])){<br/>
        $modal = $_SESSION['modal'];<br/>
        <script>//your alert script</script>

    }<br/>
    unset($_SESSION["modal"]);<br/>
?><br/>
```

Comment: hope this helpful